# Reactjs Life Cycle Function Rendering Twice

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about the mechanics of `componentDidMount`. I'm building out a weather app that uses an external api to get forecast data for a city.

My Forecast Container is built like this

```
var React = require('react');
var Forecast = require('../components/Forecast');
var weatherHelpers = require('../utils/weather');

var ForecastContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      isLoading: true,
      forecastData: {}
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function(){
    weatherHelpers.getCityForecast(this.props.routeParams.city)
    .then(function(results){
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        forecastData: results
      })
    }.bind(this))
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <Forecast
        city={this.props.routeParams.city}
        isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
        forecastData={this.state.forecastData}
      />
      )
  }
});

module.exports = ForecastContainer;
```

I'm using axios to send an http get request to the weather api and storing the functionality inside a helper file called weatherHelpers.

```
function Forecast(props) {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>Forecast component</div>
  )
}
```

When I log props from my Forecast component, it is logged twice. Once with the initial state and again with the updated state. Is this just state life operates: a lag between initial state and running instructions inside componentDidMount? Is there a re-rendering of my component (hence the two console logs). If so, what is the mechanism that is at work. How is the component listening to it's state?

Comment: I don't see `componentWillMount` here.

Comment: Looks like @Coder_Nick meant `componentDidMount`. I edited the question because that threw me off in my initial answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `render` runs before `componentDidMount` in the lifecycle (see [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)).

The order is:

```
constructor()
componentWillMount()
render()
componentDidMount()
```

By the time `componentDidMount` has run, `render` has already run. The state change in `componentDidMount` then triggers another render.

**Edit**

My old (incorrect, but modified now) answer is below, but something else to keep in mind. If you changed `componentDidMount` to `componentWillMount`, it would still render twice, because of the promise:

```
weatherHelpers.getCityForecast(this.props.routeParams.city).then(...
```

When the component is initially rendered, `componentWillMount` would run, set up the promise, and then render itself. Then the promise completes, updates the state, and React renders again based on the state change.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a promise. `render` will run before `componentDidMount`, it's the `setState` which triggers another `render`

Comment: Good point; I had my head stuck in `componentWillMount` space because of the wording of the question. Submit your answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Editing mine in case you don't see this, but I'll defer to you if you post.

Answer (score 0):

I think when that on componentDidMount you are sending the request and telling it to execute the code in then when you get the response.

You set that event and render the component. Then when the response comes back, it runs the function passed to then, updating the state.

You are passing down this state as props to the Forecast component, this notices that the props have changed and that causes the new render.